# How to keep rows with the first value (str) of the group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have troubles finding a proper solution for the following case: Given is the pandas dataframe (sorted by descending date)

---

```
ID  Location    Date
1   x           01.03.20
1   x           27.02.20
1   y           22.02.20
1   x           20.02.20
2   p           04.02.20
2   p           01.03.20
2   y           01.02.20
3   z           29.02.20
3   z           27.02.20
3   z           24.02.20
3   z           23.02.20
3   e           21.02.20
3   z           20.02.20
```

now i would like to keep for each ID only the rows with most recent location (datatype: string) - meaning the end result should look like this:

```
ID  Location    Date
1   x           01.03.20
1   x           27.02.20
2   p           04.02.20
2   p           01.03.20
3   z           29.02.20
3   z           27.02.20
3   z           24.02.20
3   z           23.02.20
```

I was thinking about iterating over the complete dataframe (~500000) rows but would prefer another solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks 
Julian

Comment: In your example, ID 1 has two locations x where the location x at date 01.03.20 is more recent than the one at 27.02.20. What do you mean by "rows with most recent location (datatype: string)"? Is this a filter by Date > X?

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your comment. Basically I want to find out how much time an ID has spent at the last logged location. The Dataframe is sorted by date and a Location can appear several Times for each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially want to find the `[ID,location]` set that is most recent for each `ID` and pull that data. Since it's sorted by date, it's even easier, as you just need the first location per ID. Something like:

```
ind = df.groupby('ID')['Location'].first().reset_index().set_index(['ID','Location']).index

df.set_index(['ID','Location']).loc[ind]


>>
             Date
ID Location          
1  x         01.03.20
   x         27.02.20
2  p         04.02.20
   p         01.03.20
3  z         29.02.20
   z         27.02.20
   z         24.02.20
   z         23.02.20
```

I feel like there's a less convoluted way to do this but I just can't see it...

EDIT: Your question brought me to another solution, using `cumsum`:
Basically we use `cumsum` to make a "count" per ID of how different locations.

```
df['loc2'] = df.Location.shift(1) #this gives previous row's Location
df['is_same'] = df.Location != df.loc2 #this marks True when the next Location is the same.
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID')['is_same'].cumsum()
```

Finally:

```
df[df['cumsum']==1]
>

    ID Location      Date loc2  is_same  cumsum
0    1        x  01.03.20  NaN     True     1.0
1    1        x  27.02.20    x    False     1.0
4    2        p  04.02.20    x     True     1.0
5    2        p  01.03.20    p    False     1.0
7    3        z  29.02.20    y     True     1.0
8    3        z  27.02.20    z    False     1.0
9    3        z  24.02.20    z    False     1.0
10   3        z  23.02.20    z    False     1.0
```

This only gives the first occurrence of the first Location, as you need!

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the reply. In my dataset I also have the case for some IDs that a Location is appearing again - e.g. Locations for ID = 1: x - x - p - y - x. If I apply the proposed code the result would be x - x - x with the respective Dates but my goal would be only to get the First two entries, so: x - x. Do you have a proposal for that?

Comment: @julio_123 second solution should do that for you now - as long as dataset is sorted by dates properly.

Comment: thanks so much for your update :) thats exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an indicator that the `(Id, Location)` is the same as the first for that Id. Performing a `cumsum()` on this indicator will allow you then to filter the DataFrame to get the desired response.

```
most_recent_loc = df.groupby('Id')['Location'].first().reset_index()
most_recent_loc['visited_recently'] = 0
df = df.merge(most_recent_loc, how='left', 
                left_on=['Id', 'Location'], 
                right_on=['Id', 'Location']).fillna(1)
df['visited_recently'] = df.groupby('Id')['visited_recently'].cumsum()
df[df['visited_recently'] == 0].drop(columns='visited_recently')
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer, but I will stick to solution above as it considers the case I explained in my comment above.